# Can you load a PHP include with a JS timeout?

Tags: php, javascript, load, timeout

I've got some PHP that I don't want loaded immediately.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
<?php
  // ... snip ...
?>
<div class="footer">
    <other divs/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout( function() { 
            <?php include(CHILD_DIR . '/modules/partner-init.php'); ?>
        }, 10000);
    </script>
</div>
```

That seems a little sloppy, but before I jump in to it, I want to know if it's either a) possible, or b) if there's a better way

Comment: Look into ajax, it is the only possible way

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time someone asks how to mix JS and PHP in this way, I'd have, like, a ton of dollars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, the include would be placed right there. The PHP is executed on the server before it's sent to the client for the JS to be executed.

Also, it wouldn't hurt to just do it and see what happens, it will help you learn.

If you want PHP to be executed later, you could request the page in an AJAX request. This will make it so the PHP is executed from the request, which can be controlled/timed by JS.

Answer (score 1):

What you literally want is not possible, but the obvious solution is to echo everything out in the html on page-load and simply hide the `div` or element in question. Then you show it whenever you want using javascript.

No ajax or additional requests needed; it saves you a roundtrip to the server.

Comment: Depending on what OP wants this could be the best solution.